# Why doesn't this USB-C PCI card work?

Tags: hardware-failure, sata, pci, usb-c

I'm trying to install a USB-C device with little success.

Output device requires:

- ≤ 8 W
- 4.75-5.25V, 1.5A

The card is supposed to conform to USB-C spec. The device powers on, but continually restarts. The manual for the device states this happens when there is not enough power.

I'm looking at [this PCB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nO6TF.jpg) and I just don't understand how the "5V" connector gets to the outputs. Possibilities:

- The board's design is incomplete
- The board is defective - the SATA power interface does not feel very solid when inserting the plug
- The SATA cable is defective - unlikely, I tried 2 cables both of which are powering my hard drives with no issue
- The USB-C cable is defective - also unlikely, it carried enough power when plugged into the wall adapter

[Image of chipboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nO6TF.jpg)

Comment: How many watts is your power supply?  When you say **device restarts** are you talking about the pci-e card or the device plugged into the USB-C port?  What are you plugging into the USB-C port and how many watts does it need?  Also I don't know the make and model of the pci-e device so I can't look it up anywhere.

Comment: 750 W. I'm talking about the device plugged into the port.

Comment: An external display. It requires <= 8 W according to the manufacturer.
https://www.bestbuy.ca/en-ca/product/axgear-usb-type-c-pci-e-card-2-port-hub-usb-c-pcie-express-controller-usb-3-1-adapter/12314229.aspx?

Comment: I can't find the manual online, and the best buy and other pages don't list the rated power output of the card.  Does the manual list a power output rating and whether or not that the number is per port or for both ports?

Comment: Previously, I have done some research on similar cards and USB type C, when implemented properly, supposedly can do 5A.  Back to reality, 99% of the cards I found were in the 1A to 1.5A range.

Comment: https://www.startech.com/Cards-Adapters/USB-3.0/Cards/2-port-pcie-usb-3-1-card~PEXUSB312C   This card actually states it provides up to 3A of power per port.

Comment: This card looks visually identical as far as I can tell, and is listed as being able to output 5V and 2A on each port: https://www.amazon.ca/SDS-Express-Connector-Superspeed-Windows/dp/B01NCQUET8/ref=sr_1_5

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72523/discussion-between-buildingsramen-and-cybernard).

Comment: You would have to do a component by component comparison.  The axgear company doesn't even have a website.  Cards of this super generic design are usually 900ma, especially when they omit the ratings from their documentation.